# Magento checkmaxlenght for text attributes

Tags: magento, attributes

I need to limit text field length for an attribute ("inspiration") similar as for meta_description. I have tried copying the code block in Attributes.php (\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab):

```
if ($form->getElement('meta_description')) {
            $form->getElement('meta_description')->setOnkeyup('checkMaxLength(this, 255);');
        }
```

and replacing "meta_description" with "inspiration", but it doesn't work. Could anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say because you don't define "doesn't work" precisely.

My guess would be, that the `<form>` containing your `inspiration` input field is some *custom* template and doesn't contain the needed JavaScript method `checkMaxLength()`*.

```
function checkMaxLength(Object, MaxLen)
{
    if (Object.value.length > MaxLen-1) {
        Object.value = Object.value.substr(0, MaxLen);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

---

<sub>* which is usually only defined in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit.phtml`</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Seach for the phtml who build this part of code and make it with jQuery.